# Global rotation of child bone?

Tags: bones, constraints

How can I get the global rotation of a bone from the Blender editor? I want to constrain a bone to have only that rotation, regardless of its parent. I want it in pose mode.

Comment: Pose mode is what i meant

Comment: I want to make it so if my arm draws back, my wrist is facing the same direction so im still holding my gun.

Comment: Yes but what bone needs it? and what do i target it to? the arm bone? I tried that :(

Comment: Ok ill await that answer

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. Create an IK bone directly at the root of your hand.
2. Constraint lower arm to the IK bone.
3. Make sure inhert rotation for the IK bone is turned on.

[image]

Comment: I already have a ik on the hand root. It didnt work. I think you misunderstood, if my arm bends down, I want my hand to remain upright.

Comment: Cant i just get the world rotation?

Comment: The concept is the same , have you tried rigging the eyeball? So no matter how your character moves they can stay on a target? Treat your hands like eyeball and you probably achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: I dont have eyeballs. Just arms. How about bone drivers?

Answer (score 1):

I have done some testing on my own and here is the blend file.
You can download it to test if that is what you are looking for.
The rig is done on the left hand.

Basically, I have created an IK target for the hand so that it
always points at the target you tell it to regardless how you
move the arm. It works like the way you would constraint the eyes
to a target.

[image]